# Require как подставлять переменную, а не прописывать путь

Tags: javascript

хочу вставлять в require значение из стейта для того что менять src в img. Но выходит ошибка Failed to compile.

```
import React from 'react'
import Section from '../../components/container/section'
import HeaderTitle from '../../components/HeaderTitle/HeaderTitle'
import Container from '../../components/container/container'
import DescText from '../../components/descText/descText'
import './AboutUs.scss'
class AboutUs extends React.Component{
    state = {
        aboutUsContent: [
            {img: '"../../images/"Rectangle 2 copy 2.jpg'},
            {img: '"../../images/"Rectangle 2 copy 3-2.jpg'},
            {img: '"../../images/"Rectangle 2 copy 3.jpg'}
        ]
    }

    render(){



        return(
            <Section sectionName="AboutUs">
                <Container>
                    <div className="AboutUs-content">
                        <HeaderTitle headerText="About Us" pText="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet event landing template"/>

                    <div className="AboutUs-desc">
                        <div className="AboutUs-desc__slide">
                            <div className="AboutUs-Regtangle"></div>
                            <img id="imageSlide" src={require("../../images/comp.png")}></img>

                        </div>
                        <div className="AboutUs-desc__p">
                            <div className="AboutUs-desc__p__second">
                            <DescText descTextH3="We Actually Do amazing works" descTextP="A visual approach is an approach to a runway at an airport 
                                conducted under instrument flight rules. 
                                The pilot must at all times have either the airport or the preceding aircraft in approach correct sight. conducted under instrument flight rules. The pilot must at all times.">
                            </DescText>
                            <DescText descTextH3="why we are the great?" descTextP="A visual approach is an approach to a runway at an airport 
        conducted under instrument flight rules.
        The preceding aircraft in approach correct sight.">
                            </DescText>

                            <div className="AboutUs-arrows">
                                <div className="AboutUs-arrows__box">
                                    <button id="arrowBack">dsa</button>
                                    <button id="arrowNext">das</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </Section>
        )

    }
    componentDidMount(){
    var count = 0;
        const movingUp= ()=>{
            ++count
            let image = document.getElementById('imageSlide')
            console.log(image.src)
            if(count==6){
                count=0
            }
            image.scr={require({this.state.aboutUsContent[count].img})} // Не работает
        }
        const movingBack= ()=>{
            --count
            let image = document.getElementById('imageSlide')
            if(count==-1){
                count=5
            }
            image.scr={require({this.state.aboutUsContent[count].img})} // Не работает
        }



    let arrowBack = document.getElementById("arrowBack")
        arrowBack.addEventListener('click', movingBack)
    let arrowNext = document.getElementById("arrowNext")
        arrowNext.addEventListener('click', movingUp)


    }
}
export default AboutUs
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать динамические импорты

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
   const [imgRes, setImgRes] = useState();
   const loadImg = useCallback(async () => {
      const resource = await import('./image.png');

      setImgRes(resource);
   }, [setImgRes]);

   return (
      <div className="App">
        <img src={imgRes} alt="" />
        <button onClick={loadImg}>Загрузить картинку</button>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Сделал пример на CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-moore-dy5qy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Возможность поддерживается Webpack начиная со второй версии